# how to run bash code in a loop in google colab

Tags: python, bash, loops, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a loop that requires the bash command --
`!python3 -m runner.player_1`

but when I make it into loop:

```
for player1 in range(0, 100, 1):
    !python3 -m "runner.player_" + str(player1)
```

it doesn't work and returns the error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `python3 -m "runner.player_" + str(player1)'
```

how can i fix this? thank you

Comment: Is this in a python script, or a bash script? You seem to be mixing the two languages' syntaxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native Bash loop would look like

```
for i in {0..99}; do python3 -m runner.player_$i; done
```

You can replace the semicolons with newlines, and/or add a newline after `do` if you like. I'm guessing you will want it literally as a one-liner.

This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), though; surely it would be better if whatever code implements these 100 modules would be refactored so that you can run them all sequentially in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call it as python function using `os.system`, not as magic command.

```py
import os
for player1 in range(0, 100, 1):
    os.system("python3 -m runner.player_" + str(player1))
```

Comment: not sure why, but this method doesn't work for me :(